# Yii2: задать единый фильтр для ActiveRecord

Tags: yii2, activerecord

Нашел, что в Yii 1 был такое метод как `beforeFind()`. Как такое можно сделать в Yii2?

Например, я решил сделать функцию скрытия неких объектов. Добавил поле `visible`. И что бы не ходить по всему коду и не искать, где это используется, могу ли я в одном месте написать, что

`where(['visible' => 1])`

и оно применится всюду?

Answer (score 0):

Да, такое можно реализовать с помощью переопределения метода `find()` в модели. В этом методе необходимо указать использование своего класса `ActiveQuery`.

```
class Comment extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function find()
    {
        return new CommentQuery(get_called_class());
    }
}
```

Класс запроса может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
class CommentQuery extends ActiveQuery
{
    public function active($state = true)
    {
        return $this->andWhere(['active' => $state]);
    }
}
```

Далее можно получить активные и неактивные записи с помощью такого кода:

```
 $comments = Comment::find()->active()->all();
 $inactiveComments = Comment::find()->active(false)->all();
```

В методах построения запросов рекомендуется использовать методы `andWhere()` и `orWhere()`, чтобы не переопределить условия, заданные ранее.

Это также работает в случае использования связей

```
class Customer extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function getActiveComments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::className(), ['customer_id' => 'id'])->active();
    }
}

$customers = Customer::find()->with('activeComments')->all();
```

Либо так

```
$customers = Customer::find()->with([
    'comments' => function($q) {
        $q->active(false);
    }
])->all();
```

Comment: если у меня уже есть проект и я сделаю так как вы говорите, мне все равно надо искать по всему коду, где это используется

Comment: Желательно, конечно, подчистить существующий код. Но если выборка комментов всегда через реляцию производится, то можно описать условие в  существующей реляции, а старый код подрихтовать по мере использования.